# PHP not being parsed by Apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm running WAMP right now and for whatever reason, the server is not interpreting PHP.

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled? Does it do the same when you use `<?php` instead?

Comment: I'm not very bright, I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any reason to vote this down.... He/She just didn't know.

Comment: +1 from me! I know I've asked simple questions before too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you don't have short-hand tags enabled.

Short-hand opening tag looks like `<?` as you've posted. The full-length tag is `<?php`. Check php.ini to see whether or not short-hand is enabled.

Comment: you should set

    **short_open_tag = On**

in php.ini

And dont forget: you allways needs to **restart** your **Apache**.